# Show/Hide Div based on content within that div

Tags: jquery, html, show-hide

I'm looking to hide the image containers on these pages based on if there's an actual image uploaded to that specific event, or if the placeholder image is inside of the container. The only thing that differentiates the two images is the path to the image, of course, and the alt tag. I'm obviously looking to hide the image containers container the placeholder images. (th_noimage.jpg is the placeholder image)

http://www.salvatorechiarelli.com/List/February

```
<div class="productListImageContainer">
<a id="MainContent_controlProductsList1_lvItems_ctrl0_lnkImage_0" href="/View/Thursday-February-14th-2013-7P-M">
<img id="MainContent_controlProductsList1_lvItems_ctrl0_produtImage_0" alt="Thursday, February 14th, 2013 @ 7P.M." src="/ProductImages/112229/th_noimage.jpg">
</a>
</div>

<div class="productListImageContainer">
<a id="MainContent_controlProductsList1_lvItems_ctrl0_lnkImage_1" href="/View/Sunday-February-17th-2013-3P-M">
<img id="MainContent_controlProductsList1_lvItems_ctrl0_produtImage_1" alt="Sunday, February 17th, 2013 @ 3P.M." src="/ProductImages/112229/th_be4a17_feb_17_13.png">
</a>
</div>
```

Basically a script that says hide productListImageContainer if it contains th_noimage.jpg. I wish I was a programmer, but it's completely over my head.

This is an ecommerce CMS section of the site that I manipulated to work as a listing for my clients events, by the way. Thanks for any help that could be provided!

Comment: Are you using jQuery on this page?

Comment: @nathanhayfield Tried googling a few stackoverflow examples, but not much luck. I figured it was this simple that I wouldn't have to show the examples.

Comment: @JeromyFrench Of course. Can't seem to figure out why I can't get the script to work for a different part of the site too, though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use jQuery, you could probably do:

```
$('img[src$="th_noimage.jpg"]').closest('.productListImageContainer').hide();
```

to hide the placeholders

Comment: Yes I am! Works perfect! Thanks! You rule!

Comment: Any idea why $('img[src$="lg_noimage.jpg"]').closest('#productImageContainer').hide(); doesn't work on this page? http://www.salvatorechiarelli.com/View/Thursday-February-14th-2013-7P-M

Comment: Because in that situation, the filename is md_noimage instead of lg_noimage, you could probably change the code to $('img[src$="_noimage.jpg"]').closest('#productImageContainer').hide(); to get them all

Comment: Wow, I'm dumb, was using the wrong image name...Thanks! Works perfect. Much appreciated.